# Github-style page transitions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any example code for something like that (and somehow changing the URL without forcing a reload, with no #)? Is it using HTML5 to replace history?

Comment: You've got two questions which are unrelated other than one particular website does both things you are looking to do. I strongly suggest splitting them in to two actual questions. (Well, at least one of them has many duplicates on SO so I'd delete that one and use the search instead)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They explain how they do this in [their blog post](https://github.com/blog/760-the-tree-slider) and yes, it uses the [HTML5 History API](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/history.html).

They even show you exactly how it's done in their [jquery-pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) project.

Also, you can get example code for anything you see on the web via view source, finding the Javascript file, and then if it's minified passing it through something like http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: To copy it verbatim, yes, depending on the laws where you live and what the other has specified in terms of copyright. To look at, or 'view source', no.